# Internet Explorer caching files

Tags: internet-explorer, caching

I am trying to test a flash game and for the life of me I can't seem to delete the cached image, sound and swf files for my game. I have of course deleted my browsing history and have the temporary internet files and website files box checked. That didn't work. Next I tried deleting stuff in the appdata folder underneath microsoft/internet explorer folders. That didn't work either. I can't test my game code with these files being cached. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a full refresh of the page using Ctrl+F5?

Comment: It isn't a webpage that is the issue. It is a flash game that has lots of png, jpg, mp3 and swf files. These are all being cached.